# Obtain remote IP from QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, http, connection, ip, qnetworkaccessmanager

When using QNetworkAccessManager, is there any way to get http connection info, like local ip/remote ip?
I need to record such connection info for each QNetworkReply/Request pair.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `QHostInfo` and from there you can query for remote and local ips/names.

Take a look at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qhostinfo.html#details

Comment: use QHostInfo can query host ip address. But I need to be aware that real connection info for each QNetworkReply. At least, should contain Port number. And, for some situation, DNS lookup result differs from each query.

Comment: By some research of Qt source code, I think it's impossible to get tcpsocket connection info from QNetworkAccessManager. I tried to modify the Qt4.8.0's some classes: QNetworkreply, Qhttpnetworkreply, Qhttpnetworkconnectionchannel, Qhttpthreaddelegate, Qnetworkaccesshttpbackend, to report connection info from kernel within exist signal. It seemed success.

Comment: Hey @powerpcpm: I know it's been a long time. Have you by any chance documented the changes you made to Qt source?